# "Please cast your vote" Remains After I Have Voted

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The red bar at the top of the page which says "Please cast your vote in the GIS 2011 community moderator election!" is quite handy.  But now that I have made my three choices for the moderators, I would expect that bar to dismiss itself.  Yes, I know there is an X at the right end of the bar, but I think that it would be smoother if it dismissed itself.  If I want to go back to the election, I can just refer to "Please participate in the GIS 2011 community moderator election"

Answer (score 2):

The notify bar is simply designed to be dismissed by clicking the [x] to close it, in all cases.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether most of users aware this or need to report as bug in the design. After voting for 3 moderators, you can visit the page again and change your selection. I hope that it allowed until voting period active. However, it is not common practice in normal voting.

I found it is useful as allow user to modify the selection if they found they made mistake or get to know more on moderator after voting and want to change their selection or order.